# Cannot add navigation.php in another php file

Tags: php, mysql

Display a
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MySQLDB in /home/web/public_html/loginfinal/include/database.php on line 13 
when I use the below code.

```
<?php $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>
<?
include("include/session.php");
if(!$session->isVerified() && $session->logged_in){
header("Location: email.php");
}
?>

<html>
<title>Login page</title>
<body>

<?php 
include_once($site_root ."/loginfinal/nav_top.php");
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?
//others detail
?>
```

After read about this problem now I use the code below which dose't show any error also does't show the navigation too. where is my problem please?

```
<?php $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>
<?
include("include/session.php");
if(!$session->isVerified() && $session->logged_in){
header("Location: email.php");
?>

<html>
<title>Login page</title>
<body>

<?php 
if(!class_exists('MySQLDB') == true){
include_once($site_root ."/loginfinal/nav_top.php");}
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?
//others detail
?>
```

This is my Nnav_top.php

```
<?
include("include/session.php");
include("db.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">

<head>
<META name="TITLE" content="navigation">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UFT-8'/>
<title>navigation</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="image.jpg" width="55" height="40">BD Showbiz</a>
        </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> <br>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/bd_About%20Us.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> <br>About Us</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> <br>Service<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"> <a href="#">Event Management</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/bd_Corporate%20Event.htm">Corporate Event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wedding.htm">Wedding Event</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/bd_Others%20Event.htm">Others Privet Event</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/bd_Offer.htm">Special Offer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> <br>Web Service<b class="caret"></b></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/bd_contact_us.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map- marker"></span> <br>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="get" action="/search.htm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="tfq" class="form-control" name="q">
                <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" checked />
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php
if($session->logged_in){
echo '<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navLogin"><span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <br>'.$session->username.' <b class="caret"></b>         </a>';
echo '                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">';
echo '                        <li><a href=/main.php>Profile</a></li>';
echo '                        <li><a href=/useredit.php>Setting</a></li>';
echo '                        <li class="divider"></li>';
if($session->isAdmin()){
  echo '<li><a href=/admin/admin.php>Admin Center</a></li>';
}
echo '                        <li><a href=process.php>Logout</a></li>';
echo '                  </ul>';
}else{
echo '<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navLogin"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> <br>login <b class="caret"></b></a>';
echo '                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">';
echo '                      <form style="margin: 0px" accept-charset="UTF-8"   action="process.php" method="post">';

echo '                      </form>';
echo '                  </ul>';
}
?>
           <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
<?php
global $dbh;
//Check image address
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT u_imgurl FROM blog_users WHERE username='$session- >username'");
if(!$result2) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$u_imgurl = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
$u_imgurl = $row["u_imgurl"];
}
if (empty($u_imgurl)) $u_imgurl = "picture.jpg";
    //End Check image address
if($session->logged_in){
echo '<li><img alt="" src="/loginfinal/img/'.$u_imgurl.'" width="40" height="40"     class="img-responsive img-circle profile-img"/></li>';
}else{
echo '<li><a href="/loginfinal/register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">  </span> <br>Sign Up</a></li>';
}
?>

           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

My Database.php

```
<?
/**
 * Database.php
 * 
 * The Database class is meant to simplify the task of accessing
 * information from the website's database.
 *
 * 
 */
include("constants.php");

class MySQLDB
{
var $connection;         //The MySQL database connection
var $num_active_users;   //Number of active users viewing site
var $num_active_guests;  //Number of active guests viewing site
var $num_members;        //Number of signed-up users
/* Note: call getNumMembers() to access $num_members! */

/* Class constructor */
function MySQLDB(){
  /* Make connection to database */
  $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());

  /**
   * Only query database to find out number of members
   * when getNumMembers() is called for the first time,
   * until then, default value set.
   */
  $this->num_members = -1;

  if(TRACK_VISITORS){
     /* Calculate number of users at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

     /* Calculate number of guests at site */
     $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
  }
}

function confirmUserPass($username, $password){
  /* Add slashes if necessary (for query) */
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $username = addslashes($username);
  }

  /* Verify that user is in database */
  $q = "SELECT password FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
     return 1; //Indicates username failure
  }

  /* Retrieve password from result, strip slashes */
  $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $dbarray['password'] = stripslashes($dbarray['password']);
  $password = stripslashes($password);

  /* Validate that password is correct */
  if($password == $dbarray['password']){
     return 0; //Success! Username and password confirmed
  }
  else{
     return 2; //Indicates password failure
  }
}

function confirmUserID($username, $userid){
  /* Add slashes if necessary (for query) */
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $username = addslashes($username);
  }

  /* Verify that user is in database */
  $q = "SELECT userid FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
     return 1; //Indicates username failure
  }

  /* Retrieve userid from result, strip slashes */
  $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $dbarray['userid'] = stripslashes($dbarray['userid']);
  $userid = stripslashes($userid);

  /* Validate that userid is correct */
  if($userid == $dbarray['userid']){
     return 0; //Success! Username and userid confirmed
  }
  else{
     return 2; //Indicates userid invalid
  }
}

function usernameTaken($username){
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
     $username = addslashes($username);
  }
  $q = "SELECT username FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  return (mysql_numrows($result) > 0);
}

function usernameBanned($username){
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
     $username = addslashes($username);
  }
  $q = "SELECT username FROM ".TBL_BANNED_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  return (mysql_numrows($result) > 0);
}

function addNewUser($username, $password, $email, $emailvcode){
  $time = time();
  /* If admin sign up, give admin user level */
  if(strcasecmp($username, ADMIN_NAME) == 0){
     $ulevel = ADMIN_LEVEL;
     $verifystatus = 0;
  }else{
     $ulevel = USER_LEVEL;
     $verifystatus = 0;
  }
  $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password', '0', $ulevel,     '$email', '$verifystatus', '$emailvcode', '$time')";
  return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}

function updateUserField($username, $field, $value){
  $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".$field." = '$value' WHERE username = '$username'";
  return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}

function getUserInfo($username){
  $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  /* Error occurred, return given name by default */
  if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
     return NULL;
  }
  /* Return result array */
  $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  return $dbarray;
}

/**
* retrieve email verification code
*/
function emailVerify($vcode){
  $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE emailverifier = '$vcode'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  /* Verification code exists, verify user and return true */
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
  $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET verifystatus = '1' WHERE emailverifier = '$vcode'";
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
     return 1;
  }
  /* verification code doesn't exist return false */
  else
  {
    return 0;  
  }
}

function getNumMembers(){
  if($this->num_members < 0){
     $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_USERS;
     $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
     $this->num_members = mysql_numrows($result);
  }
  return $this->num_members;
}

function calcNumActiveUsers(){
  /* Calculate number of users at site */
  $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS;
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->num_active_users = mysql_numrows($result);
}

function calcNumActiveGuests(){
  /* Calculate number of guests at site */
  $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS;
  $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->num_active_guests = mysql_numrows($result);
}

function addActiveUser($username, $time){
  $q = "UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET timestamp = '$time' WHERE username = '$username'";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);

  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $q = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$time')";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveUsers();
}

/* addActiveGuest - Adds guest to active guests table */
function addActiveGuest($ip, $time){
  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $q = "REPLACE INTO ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS." VALUES ('$ip', '$time')";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
}

/* These functions are self explanatory, no need for comments */

/* removeActiveUser */
function removeActiveUser($username){
  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS." WHERE username = '$username'";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveUsers();
}

/* removeActiveGuest */
function removeActiveGuest($ip){
  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS." WHERE ip = '$ip'";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
}

/* removeInactiveUsers */
function removeInactiveUsers(){
  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $timeout = time()-USER_TIMEOUT*60;
  $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_USERS." WHERE timestamp < $timeout";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveUsers();
}

/* removeInactiveGuests */
function removeInactiveGuests(){
  if(!TRACK_VISITORS) return;
  $timeout = time()-GUEST_TIMEOUT*60;
  $q = "DELETE FROM ".TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS." WHERE timestamp < $timeout";
  mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
  $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
}

function query($query){
  return mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
}
};
$database = new MySQLDB;
?>
```

Comment: You should just use include_once() with the class file you're including in nav_top.php. Actually, you should always use include_once() OR require_once() for class.file includes.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't show because you're checking if the class is non-existent, which it is, because it's complaining about it being redeclared (re-created).

- Change all occurrences of `include`/`require` to `include_once`/`require_once`.

That will make it so files are only included once within a request, meaning the class isn't re-declared.

Comment: Its not work also. My nav_top.php is a bootstrap navigation file which have include css and js file. Is it any problem?

Comment: Please post `nav_top.php` file. HTML/CSS files won't cause this, no. What files include `database.php`?

Comment: Ok, also add my nav_top.php and database.php above.

Comment: @jainul Does `include/session.php` include `database.php`?

Answer (score 0):

At the page top add:
if(!class_exists('MySQLDB')== true){
require_once($site_root ."/loginfinal/nav_top.php");}

with $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

So the problem solved and its look like

```
<?php $site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
if(!class_exists('MySQLDB')== true){
require_once($site_root ."/loginfinal/nav_top.php");}
?>
```

Thank you all